# Using Resources in C# as a database

Tags: c#

I am trying to implement the Data Access Object (DAO) Pattern in C#
Have 3 classes

> **1.School    with attributes**

```
    - String name
    - List int optionCodes
    - int contactNo
    - String webSite
    - String address
```

> **2.SchoolDAO interface    with methods**

```
  public List<School> getAllSchools;
  public School getSchool(String _name); 
  public void updateSchool(School _school);
  public void deleteSchool(School _school);
```

3. School DAOImpl

This is where I want to access an XML file SchoolList as my persistent data

I would like to use Properties.Resources where it is stored but am not sure how to implement the following CRUD methods in C#

```
class DAOImpl
{
    String dataBase = SchoolDataAccessObjectPattern.Properties.Resources.SchoolContactDetails;
    List<School> schoolList= new List<School>();

    public List<School> getAllSchools;
    public School getSchool(String _name);
    public void addSchool(School _school);
    public void updateSchool(School _school);
    public void deleteSchool(School _school);

}
```

Comment: SchoolContactDetail is the XML file

Comment: You cannot modify project resource files at runtime.  `Properties.Resources` is only useful for looking up static information.